# How to convert a PDF into image exactly similar to the PDF with PHP/Imagemagik/Ghostscript

Tags: php, imagemagick, gd, tcpdf, ghostscript

Im generating PDF documents with PHP(TCPDF is the library behind) and for displaying them Im converting them as images using ghostscript, and displaying the previews, but the preview doesnt actually similar to the PDF document.

The code Im using to convert is here

```
$pdf = 'my_report.pdf';
$output = 'my_preview.jpg';
$quality=90;
$res='300x300';
$exportPath=$output;
set_time_limit(900);
exec("'gs' '-dNOPAUSE' '-sDEVICE=jpeg' '-dUseCIEColor' '-dTextAlphaBits=4' '-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4' '-o$exportPath' '-r$res' '-dJPEGQ=$quality' '$pdf'",$output);
```

and the preview generated with the code for this document is right below
[image]

where as my actual PDF file looks like below
[image]

You can see a lot of inequalities between, I need a way to convert like just a copy of it.
and im sure there is nothing wrong in the PDf report, I tried it uploading it into Google mail, that gave a perfect image, and I did convert the PDf into jpeg here 
http://pdf2jpg.net/
That to gave a perfect copy of the document, only the Imagemagick/Gjostscript is unable to generate an exact one.
Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to view the 'correct' display of the PDF ? Does Ghostscript issue you any warnings when rendering ?

It looks to me like there 'may' be fonts missing in your original PDF file, which will lead to font substitution.

Why are you using -dUseCIEColor ? This will almost certainly lead to colour shifts, which I also see in your images. If you have a good reason for using this, what is it ? If you don't have a good reason, don't do that.

Is the second image a JPEG ? The first clearly is, and jpeg is a lossy compression, have you tried using TIFF instead ?

It is always useful with these sorts of questions to post a link to the original PDF file, so that some investigation can be done, without that, this is all guesswork I'm afraid.